# Can't create program...Pycharm...Lists?

Tags: python, list, pycharm

I am trying to make a program that shows up a list of 40 values, selects 4 values, and display if the value is available in the list, if it's under the 40 values, and not available if it's above 40 values.
The code for the program is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
list = list(range(1,41))
print(list)
listValues = []
for i in range(1,5): #1,2,3,4
    value = int(input("Write the value" +str(i)+":")) #Write the value 1
    listValues.append(value)
print(listValues)

for value in listValues:
    for item in list:
        encoutered = []
    [] != True or False
    if encoutered:
        print("Value " + str(value) + " encountered.")
    else:
        print("Value " + str(value) + " not encoutered.")
```

But I can't receive when the value is encountered, only if it's not encountered and, still, includes the values encountered in those which was not encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of your code seems fine where you are reading user input and creating a list `listValues`.

The second part however looks a bit off. Replace the second part with this:

```
In [1055]: for value in listValues: 
      ...:     print(value) 
      ...:     if value in list: 
      ...:         print("Value " + str(value) + " encountered.") 
      ...:     else: 
      ...:         print("Value " + str(value) + " not encoutered.") 
      ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                  
1
Value 1 encountered.
2
Value 2 encountered.
50
Value 50 not encountered.
29
Value 29 encountered.
```

Comment: if you still can help i have another problem when I try to create a call to say how many times one value appears in the list:                                          
   from typing import Any

list = list(range(1, 41))
(...)
value = int(input("Digite o valor, para achar a posição:" +str(i) + ":"))
(...)
print(pos) //// the code for this action is below:
cont = list.count(value)
value = int(input("O valor" +str(i) + "aparece" + cont(value)))

Comment: related to this question? or an entirely new one?

Comment: Here is the link for the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61257203/problem-when-trying-to-create-another-call-call-related-to-how-many-times-a-val

Comment: looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think its what you wanted

```
list = list(range(1,41))
print(list)
listValues = []
for i in range(1,5): #1,2,3,4
    value = int(input("Write the value" +str(i)+":")) #Write the value 1
    listValues.append(value)
print(listValues)


for value in list:
    encoutered = []
    if value in listValues:
        encoutered.append(value)
    if value in encoutered:
        print("Value " + str(value) + " encountered.")
    else:
        print("Value " + str(value) + " not encoutered.")
```

You don't need a nested for loop here, 1 is enough. Just use the `value` to check if its in the `listValues`
Hope it helps