# Problem when trying to create another call? Call related to how many times a value appears in the list

Tags: list, object, int, callable

Here is the code:

```
from typing import Any

list = list(range(1, 41))
print(list)
listValues = []
for i in range(1, 5):  # 1,2,3,4
    value = int(input("Digite o valor:" + str(i) + ":"))  # Digite o valor
    listValues.append(value)
print(value)

for value in listValues:
        print(value)
        if value in list:
            print("Valor " + str(value) + " encontrado.")
        else:
            print("Valor " + str(value) + " não encontrado.")
value = int(input("Digite o valor, para achar a posição:" +str(i) + ":"))
pos = listValues.append(value)
for i in range(len(list)):
 if list[i] == value: pos = i
print(pos)
cont = list.count(value)
value = int(input("O valor" +str(i) + "aparece" + cont(value)))
```

As the last part of the code:

```
cont = list.count(value)
value = int(input("O valor" +str(i) + "aparece" + cont(value)))
```

doesn't recognize the action I want to play:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/gss/Desktop/script/lista.py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]
Digite o valor:1:30
Digite o valor:2:20
Digite o valor:3:40
Digite o valor:4:50
50
30
Valor 30 encontrado.
20
Valor 20 encontrado.
40
Valor 40 encontrado.
50
Valor 50 não encontrado.
Digite o valor, para achar a posição:4:50
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gss/Desktop/script/lista.py", line 23, in <module>
    value = input("O valor" +str(i) + "aparece" + cont(value))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: It's not advisable to have variables name same to the keywords names like `list` . Also, please put sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what your are doing, I'm gonna get that out of the way first. Next I recommend not using python keywords for variable names, it seems to work as far as i saw but just a recommendation.

File "/Users/gss/Desktop/script/lista.py", line 23, in value = input("O valor" +str(i) + "aparece" + cont(value)) TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

This error is because you tried to use 'cont' variable as if it was a function.

You defined:
**cont = list.count(value)**

cont would be an int, that why you get the type error.

Comment: yes, i tried without the value in cont(value) but still shows an error:     
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gss/Desktop/script/lista.py", line 23, in <module>
    value = int(input("O valor" +str(i) + "aparece" + cont))
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: remember that cont is an integer so we cant concatenate it to a string and it works just like that, you would have to convert it before you can use the '+' operator, an option could be f strings:    value = input(f " O valor {i} aparece {cont}"). This is just one of the many options available. 


more info:
https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: So what Error you got?..I can only make assumptions since I don't know what your aim is..but based on the errors so far..that problem should've already been solved.

Comment: this is the error i got:  value = int(input(value = input(f " O valor {i} aparece {cont}"))

Comment: That int at the front is meant to convert the value to integer. based on the expression, which even now I'm unsure if thats how you intend for it to look, value = input(f " O valor {i} aparece {cont}") gives 'value' a string type/value. This can't be converted to integer, as it has letters etc.